# Strange value for offset in fwrite

Tags: c, fwrite, ftell

For the purpose of tracing I/O calls, I have overwritten `fwrite` in a shared library that I LD_PRELOAD when running a program. In my version of `fwrite`, I get the absolute offset of the write using

```
long int pos = ftell(stream);
```

The value is then passed to a function that takes a size_t argument (so unsigned long), and the value is printed.

I encountered some calls with 18446744073709551615 as the offset (2^64 - 1), so I guess the initial long int returned by ftell was -1. These operations always wrote 10 bytes.

So my question is: what could have led the stream offset to be set to -1?

I don't trace the name of the files being accessed by those strange fwrites, so I don't know what is being accessed. Also I should precise that the program is an MPI program. It might be possible that the stream involved is actually a socket, or something else than a file...

Comment: what was `errno` set to?

Comment: `stream` not being seekable (e.g. a socket, pipe, ...) would indeed cause `ftell()` to return -1 (errno should be `EBADF` in thar case)

Comment: So I guess this is the answer. Thanks! I'll add a test that the file is a regular one. Someone should really tell me how to mark a question as answered when someone posts the answer in a comment, also...

Answer (score 0):

-1 return value from ftell means that the errno was set. Here is the relivenat text from the manpage:

> ftell() returns the current offset. Otherwise, -1 is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.